# What does &p refer to?

Tags: shell, unix, background-process, file-descriptor

I am not able to figure out what does &p do in the below script. and does `print -u4` mean that whatever argument passed is written in file decriptor 4?

```
1:  $SRVRMGRCMD |&
3:  BGPID=$!
4:  exec 4>&p
5:  exec 5<&p
6:  sleep 2
7:  # Build a list of Servers
8:  print -u4 "list servers show SBLSRVR_NAME"
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These appear to be references to co-processes (in ksh or zsh).
see https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86270/how-do-you-use-the-command-coproc-in-bash

Answer (score 1):

What language is that?

If it's bash or a shell, it creates a file descriptor to store the output, see here:

http://www.softpanorama.org/Tools/exec.shtml, specifically this part:

```
exec 3< inputfile   # Opens inputfile with file descriptor 3 for reading.
exec 4> outputfile  # Opens outputfile with file descriptor 4 for writing.
exec 5<&0   # Makes fd 5 a copy of fd 0 (standard input).
exec 6>&p   # Attach fd 6 to co-process.
```

Edited to say:

The -u*n* says to write all output to the file descriptor *n*

See here
http://alasir.com/books/bsd/428-430.html

Comment: so `print -u4` writes to file descriptor 4?

Comment: It's bash shell script.